# What does here "signature statement" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> With a silhouette that is synonymous with the MT Series' signature statement of torque and power, the MT-07 showcases a tight, compact and powerful appearance.

The text is about motorcycles. Is it some kind of distinctive characteristics?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the passage is trying to say is that the MT-07 looks like other MT-series bikes in that it's styled to look like it has lots of torque—it has a muscular appearance. MT stands for "master of torque", by the way. "Silhouette" refers to the side profile of the bike and looking at pictures of the MT-07, it looks torquey to me because it's styled sort of like a dirt bike (an upright-seater).

Street bikes, like a Yamaha YZF, have sleeker side profiles because they're meant to be ridden on streets and tracks. And street bikes emphasize horsepower while bikes with a more upright-seating position, like the MT-07, emphasize torque.

Comment: I agree. Usually a statement is a series of words. In the artsy world  a statement can be a design or a picture.  "Signature" is just a fancy way of saying "usual".